# JavaScript filter array by data from another

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array object:

```
[
    { id:1, name: 'Pedro'},
    { id:2, name: 'Miko'},
    { id:3, name: 'Bear'},
    { id:4, name: 'Teddy'},
    { id:5, name: 'Mouse'}
]
```

And I have an array with ids [1, 3, 5],

How can I filter the array object to leave records only with id's from the second one?

Comment: big question, also in the answers, which order do you prefer, the original data order, or the order of the given id for filtering?

Comment: I need to have next:  [
    { id:1, name: 'Pedro'},
    { id:3, name: 'Bear'}, { id:5, name: 'Mouse'}
]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter array when object key value is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817565/how-to-filter-array-when-object-key-value-is-in-array)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is supported, you can use it with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the items:

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Pedro'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Miko'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Bear'},
  { id: 4, name: 'Teddy'},
  { id: 5, name: 'Mouse'}
];

const filterArray = [1,3,5];

const result = array.filter(({ id }) => filterArray.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```

If includes is not supported, you can use [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead:

```js
var array = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Pedro'},
  { id: 2, name: 'Miko'},
  { id: 3, name: 'Bear'},
  { id: 4, name: 'Teddy'},
  { id: 5, name: 'Mouse'}
];

var filterArray = [1,3,5];

var result = array.filter(function(item) {
    return filterArray.indexOf(item.id) !== -1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe take a `Array.prototype.reduce` in combination with an `Array.prototype.some`. This keeps the order of the given array `need`.

```js
var data = [
        { id: 3, name: 'Bear' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Teddy' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Mouse' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Pedro' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Miko' },
    ],
    need = [1, 3, 5],
    filtered = need.reduce(function (r, a) {
        data.some(function (el) {
            return a === el.id && r.push(el);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

To keep the order of `data` you can use `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
var data = [
        { id: 3, name: 'Bear' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Teddy' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Mouse' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Pedro' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Miko' },
    ],
    need = [1, 3, 5],
    filtered = data.filter(function (a) {
        return ~need.indexOf(a.id);
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

In case the data set is small, you are ok with any of the offered solution (ones that use indexOf).

However, these solutions are O(n^2) ones, therefore, given the data set big enough, the lag can become noticeable. In this case, you should build an index prior to selecting elements.

Example:

```
function filterFast(data, ids) {
    var index = ids.reduce(function(a,b) {a[b] = 1; return a;}, {});
    return data.filter(function(item) {
        return index[item.id] === 1;
    });
}
```

And some benchmarking can be tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pmuzuh75/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop on the object array and check `hasOwnProperty` in another for loop for each ids in `[1,3,5]` (break out of the loop once an id found). (And break out of the bigger for-loop once all ids are found) If your array object is ordered (e.g. elements sorted from smallest id to biggest id) and so are your list, this solution should be quite efficient.

```
var c = 0;
for(var i =0; i< objects.length; i++){
  for(var v =0; v< list.length; v++)
     if(objects[i].hasOwnProperty(list[v])){ 
       delete objects[i]; c++; break; 
     }
  if(c===list.length) break;
}
```

or use `array.splice( i, 1 );` if you don't want an empty slot.

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` and `indexOf` will do the trick:

```js
var filteredArray = dataArray.filter(function(obj) {
  return idsArray.indexOf(obj.id) > -1;
});
```

However, `indexOf` has linear performance, and it will be called lots of times.

In ES6 you can use a set instead, whose `has` call has sublinear performance (on average):

```js
var idsSet = new Set(idsArray),
    filteredArray = dataArray.filter(obj => idsSet.has(obj.id));
```

Assuming the `toString` method of your ids is injective, you can achieve something similar in ES5:

```js
var idsHash = Object.create(null);
idsArray.forEach(function(id) {
  idsHash[id] = true;
});
var filteredArray = dataArray.filter(function(obj) {
  return idsHash[obj.id];
});
```

Comment: This only works in an environment that supports ES2015 though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your Array:

```
var data = [
    { id:1, name: 'Pedro'},
    { id:2, name: 'Miko'},
    { id:3, name: 'Bear'},
    { id:4, name: 'Teddy'},
    { id:5, name: 'Mouse'}
];

var ids = [1, 3, 5];

var filteredData = filterData(data, 'id', ids[1]);

function filterData(data, prop, values) {
    return data.filter(function(item) {
        return ~values.indexOf(item[prop]); // ~ returns 0 if indexOf returns -1
    });
}
```

See it in action [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfgw2t49/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using jQuery, another option may be:

```
var arr1 = [1, 3, 5],
    arr2 = [{ id: 1, name: 'Pedro' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Miko' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Bear' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Teddy' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Mouse' }],
    filtered = $.grep(arr2, function (item) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(item.id) > -1) {
        return true;
    }
});
```