# Typescript filter array of objects by an array

Tags: javascript

I have to filter an array of objects to get certain values based on an another array and distinct also

**Data**

```
var value:any[]

 var inventory = [
        {id: 1, quantity: 2, GroupId: 1},
        {id: 2, quantity: 0, GroupId: 2},
        {id: 1, quantity: 2, GroupId: 1}
    ];

   //data from db
   value = [1,2]
```

**My code**

```
var data = this.inventory .filter(x => x.GroupId == this.value );
```

Not able to get the filtered data, but returning empty array. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `inventory` in the `this` scope? You're declaring it as `var inventory` so it should just be `inventory.filter(..`

Comment: includes showing error like "Property 'includes' does not exist in type any[]"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter array when object key value is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817565/how-to-filter-array-when-object-key-value-is-in-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to distinct by the id field here's a solution:

```
var inventory = [
        {id: 1, quantity: 2, GroupId: 1},
        {id: 2, quantity: 0, GroupId: 2},
        {id: 1, quantity: 2, GroupId: 1}
    ];

var value = [1,2]
var data = inventory.filter(x => value.indexOf(x.GroupId)>-1).filter((elem1, pos, arr) => arr.findIndex((elem2)=>elem2.id === elem1.id) === pos);
console.log(data);
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/7xnybhLv/1/

Comment: includes showing error like "Property 'includes' does not exist in type any[]"

Comment: Use indexOf instead of includes. I updated the answer.

Comment: This worked, but I would like a better explantion as to why it worked. Why, for example, do I need the `> -1`? Why even do I need everything including and after `.findIndex`, I thought that's what `filter`did? The `> -1` is important, without it the code results in a duplicate array of `inventory`, but why?!

Comment: @RinandLen: I refactored the example code and added code comments. I hope it helps you to better understand what is happening:
https://jsfiddle.net/vrbnoqd9/

Answer (score 8):

In your code you are comparing `GroupId` with an array. You should check if array contains `GroupId` instead.

Here is how to do it:

```
var data = this.inventory.filter(x => value.includes(x.GroupId));
```

For better support you can replace [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) with [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var data = this.inventory.filter(x => value.indexOf(x.GroupId) !== -1);
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be using includes

```js
console.log([
        {id: 1, quantity: 2, GroupId: 1},
        {id: 2, quantity: 0, GroupId: 2},
        {id: 3, quantity: 2, GroupId: 1}
    ].filter(x => [1,2].includes(x.id)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the variable directly and use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var inventory = [{ id: 1, quantity: 2, GroupId: 1 }, { id: 2, quantity: 0, GroupId: 2 }, { id: 3, quantity: 2, GroupId: 1 }],
    value = [1, 2],
    data = inventory.filter(({ GroupId }) => value.includes(GroupId));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```