# Typescript get array of a column value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

i have to get array from an array of objects.

**Data**

```
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
```

**My Code**

```
var data = result1.filter(x => x.id)
```

**Expected O/P**

```
var data = [1,2,3,4]
```

my code is not returning the expected result. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript filter array of objects by an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401341/typescript-filter-array-of-objects-by-an-array)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Filter will take only the matching values, You need to use .map

```
var data = result1.map(x => x.id);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}];
    
 
var data = result1.map(t=>t.id);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use map

```
var data = result1.map(x => x.id)
```