# How to JSON with duplicate 'id' values?

Tags: php, json

I am receiving data from another site with json API.

how can I get the data of the objects with the same id number.

I try as follows but it turns blank..

there are 10 objects with the same id number
how can i get them.

The typeid number is the same but the specialvalue value is different.

```html
   {"id":4620041,"active":true,"typeid":56,"specialvalue":"0.5","fields":{"magic":{"active":true,"type":"magic","value":"1.05"},"xmagic":{"active":true,"type":"xmagic","value":"7.5"}}}
```

```html
{"id":4620045,"active":true,"typeid":56,"specialvalue":"1.5","fields":{"magic":{"active":true,"type":"magic","value":"3.05"},"xmagic":{"active":true,"type":"xmagic","value":"3.5"}}}
```

```html
    if($test->typeid =="56")
   { 
    if (specialvalue == "0.5") {
   $alta = $test->fields->magic->value;
   $uste = $test->fields->xmagic->value;
    }
   }
   
   echo $alta - $uste ;
```

Thank you in advance for your help

https://i.hizliresim.com/Pl0LL7.jpg

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: there are 10 objects with the same id number
how can i get them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter array when object key value is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817565/how-to-filter-array-when-object-key-value-is-in-array)

Comment: starting from an array of object, you can select only the ones with a specific id with `filter`as follows: `myArray.filter(obj => obj.id === mySpecificValue)`. if your request is different (maybe grouping) please specify

Comment: is not working.
Would you please help me?  https://i.hizliresim.com/5DgJnz.jpg

Comment: the json you provided is not valid. Please post real code/date if you want help.

Comment: I updated the question, would you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few observations :**

- Provided JSON is not a valid JSON.

  [image]
- It should be an `array of objects` to filter the specific data as per the requirement.

**Solution :**

```js
let jsonObj = [{
 "id": 5246752,
 "active": true,
 "typeid": 56,
 "specialvalue": "0.5",
 "fields": {
  "magic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "magic",
   "value": "1.06"
  },
  "xmagic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "xmagic",
   "value": "7.0"
  }
 }
}, {
 "id": 5246753,
 "active": true,
 "typeid": 56,
 "specialvalue": "1.5",
 "fields": {
  "magic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "magic",
   "value": "1.35"
  },
  "xmagic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "xmagic",
   "value": "3.0"
  }
 }
}, {
 "id": 5246754,
 "active": true,
 "typeid": 56,
 "specialvalue": "2.5",
 "fields": {
  "magic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "magic",
   "value": "2.0"
  },
  "xmagic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "xmagic",
   "value": "1.7"
  }
 }
}, {
 "id": 5246755,
 "active": true,
 "typeid": 56,
 "specialvalue": "3.5",
 "fields": {
  "magic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "magic",
   "value": "3.45"
  },
  "xmagic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "xmagic",
   "value": "1.25"
  }
 }
}, {
 "id": 5246756,
 "active": true,
 "typeid": 56,
 "specialvalue": "4.5",
 "fields": {
  "magic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "magic",
   "value": "6.25"
  },
  "xmagic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "xmagic",
   "value": "1.08"
  }
 }
}, {
 "id": 5246757,
 "active": true,
 "typeid": 56,
 "specialvalue": "5.5",
 "fields": {
  "magic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "magic",
   "value": "9.5"
  },
  "xmagic": {
   "active": true,
   "type": "xmagic",
   "value": "1.02"
  }
 }
}];

let filteredData = jsonObj.filter(item => item.typeid===56 && item.specialvalue==="0.5");

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: thank you @Rohit; my english is not very good, i'm sorry i can not express myself. 
The json codes that are working are available on this subject.
I am interrogating in php, I am getting other typeid s but I get 56 identity error

Comment: If this answer helps you. mark it as correct so that it will be useful for others as well. thanks

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/Pl0LL7.jpg   Thank you for your interest, I've tried everything below. it did not work

Comment: `===` comparision operator will not work here as it will compare both value as well as type . Just use `==` and try.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.filter`

```
var filteredData = data.filter(
  (el) => {
     return el.typeid===56 && el.specialvalue==="0.5";
  }
);
```

This will return only those elements with `el.typeid===56 && specialvalue==="0.5"`

Comment: Should we not close as duplicate instead?

Comment: @Rajesh Isn't the link you have provided is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes ?  It's a chain you cant control and I was specifically trying to put the ES6 version here as most of the (older) answers are ES5 based. Also this doesnt justify your downvote.

Comment: @void agree that there is a chain of post that should be marked as duplicate but are not. But this does not mean we should do the same. We can try to minimize it. Also, downvote does not mean answer is wrong. It means it is not required as question is a dupe. Also its not about use arrow functions. Objective of this post is *how to filter data* and that is addressed in linked posts(*mine and yours*).

Comment: @Rajesh indeed it is about the use of ES6 here for me. Otherwise, you can do this using for loops but that wouldn't be the preferred approach. I didn't get any "Duplicate of ..." stating this answer which OP could get so I preferred posting it. :)

Comment: @MertFırat instead of `el.typeid===56 && el.specialvalue==="0.5";` use `el.typeid===5` as your condition and you will get all the array elements with `typeid` = 56.

Comment: not work.... , if($test->typeid =="56")
    { 
     if (specialvalue == "0.5") {
    $alta = $test->fields->magic->value;
    $uste = $test->fields->xmagic->value;
     }
    }
    
    echo $alta - $uste ;; I tried this way, again the same :(

Comment: @MertFırat you are doing it using PHP and the tags you have used in your question is `Javascript` so ofcourse js code wont work in PHP. I would request you to modify your question accordingly.