# JavaScript removes objects from list based on an array of key values

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I'm trying to remove objects from an array based on their keys by passing in an array of keys.

For example, I have an array of objects called "clients":

```
[
  { id: 1, name: Tim },
  { id: 2, name: Bob },
  { id: 3, name: Joe },
]
```

Then I have another array with the keys called "ids":

```
[1,3]
```

After I filter it, I should be left with just:

```
[
  { id: 2, name: Bob },
]
```

So far I've tried this, but it returns everything:

```
filteredClients = clients.filter(n.id => !ids.includes(n.id)
```

Comment: looks like it should work.  But you need to only pass `n` in your lambda: `filteredClients = clients.filter(n => !ids.includes(n.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `n` in your callback instead of `n.id`. In this case `n` will take the value of each object of the `clients` array on each iteration. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const clients = [
     {id:1,name:"Tim"},
     {id:2,name:"Bob"},
     {id:3,name:"Joe"}
];

const ids = [1, 3];

var filteredClients = clients.filter(n => !ids.includes(n.id));

console.log(filteredClients);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [
     {id:1,name:'Tim'},
     {id:2,name:'Bob'},
     {id:3,name:'Joe'},
]
let con = [1,3]


let updatedArr = arr.find((x)=> !con.includes(x.id));
console.log(updatedArr);
```

We can use .find along with includes function of array to filter out the unwanted objects from your array

Answer (score 0):

Initial line of code:

```
filteredClients = clients.filter(n.id => !ids.includes(n.id)
```

The updated line of code should be:

```
filteredClients = clients.filter(n => !ids.includes(n.id))
```

Here instead of using n.id use n for callback in your lambda function. As in ES6 value of each object is taken by n in each iteration of given clients array

For more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817565/how-to-filter-array-when-object-key-value-is-in-array)