# Filter out array of objects by specific values and keys defined in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've this data:

```js
const data = [ 
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: -1},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1},
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 1}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: null, name: 'sauro', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: -1}, 
]
```

and I would like to filter this array by keys and values:

```js
const MANDATORY_FIELDS = [{col:'animal', v: ['', null, undefined]}, {col:'status', v: [-1, null, undefined]}]
```

So I did'w want the record that have value `'' || null || undefined` in `animal` key and neither rows with `-1 || null || undefined` in `status` key.

So the result should be:

```js
const data = [ 
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1},
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 1}, 
  {animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
  {animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 0},
  {animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0}, 
]
```

I'm starting create this function but I don't know how to continue:

```js
function filterData() {
 return data.filter((datum) => {
    return ??
  }) 
}

const filtered = filterData()
```

My problem is similar to [How to filter array when object key value is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817565/how-to-filter-array-when-object-key-value-is-in-array) but a bit more complex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter the object with a check of the properties.

```js
const
    data = [{ animal: 'cat', name: 'mu', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: -1 }, { animal: 'cat', name: 'muji', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0 }, { animal: 'cat', name: 'mine', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1 }, { animal: 'dog', name: 'fido', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 1 }, { animal: 'dog', name: 'fido2', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 1 }, { animal: 'dog', name: 'fido3', date: new Date(2021, 0, 1), status: 0 }, { animal: 'hamster', name: 'gerry', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0 }, { animal: 't-rex', name: 'dino', date: new Date(2020, 0, 1), status: 0 }, { animal: null, name: 'sauro', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0 }, { animal: 'sheep', name: 's', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: 0 }, { animal: 'sheep', name: 'sss', date: new Date(2019, 0, 1), status: -1 }],
    MANDATORY_FIELDS = [{ col: 'animal', v: ['', null, undefined] }, { col: 'status', v: [-1, null, undefined] }],
    result = data.filter(o =>
        !MANDATORY_FIELDS.some(({ col, v }) => v.includes(o[col]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This answer provides the flexibility required in the question, flexibly interpreting the `MANDATORY_FIELDS` array