# Filter array by multiple categories

Tags: javascript

I have an array of venues, each venue can have discounts of multiple categories, a user can choose to filter venues by the category of their discounts (user can choose multiple categories too!), how can I filter only the venues who have discounts of the chosen categories.

```
let selectedCategories = [1,3];

let venues =
[
    { name:'Venue 1', discountsOfCategoryOneCount:2, discountsOfCategoryTwoCount:4 },
    { name:'Venue 2', discountsOfCategoryOneCount:1, discountsOfCategoryTwoCount:8 },
    { name:'Venue 3', discountsOfCategoryOneCount:4, discountsOfCategoryTwoCount:3 }
];

let filteredResults = venues.filter((item) => /*HOW TO DO THIS*/);
```

Comment: Are you actually using both React and Vue in the same project? In any case, this question does not appear to be about either, so please remove tags that are not relevant to the question at hand. Also, please show any research you've done into the issue and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: removed react/vue tags

Comment: Or [Javascript filter array by data from another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32376651/215552)

Answer (score 1):

```
let selectedCategories = [1, 2];

let venues = [
  { name: 'Venue 1', discountsOfCategoryOneCount: 2, discountsOfCategoryTwoCount: 4 },
  { name: 'Venue 2', discountsOfCategoryOneCount: 1, discountsOfCategoryTwoCount: 8 },
  { name: 'Venue 3', discountsOfCategoryOneCount: 4, discountsOfCategoryTwoCount: 3 },
];

let filteredResults = venues.filter((item) => selectedCategories.indexOf(item.discountsOfCategoryOneCount) !== -1);

console.log(filteredResults);
```